# How to use useFormik hook with async await in onSubmit event?

Tags: reactjs, validation, next.js, formik, yup

I'm trying to find how to use async-await with useFormik hooks in onSubmit event.
I want to use axios library inside onSubmit event but with async await, but I'm not able to find the way how to use async await inside onSubmit event.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';

const SignupForm = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
    },
    onSubmit: values => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
  });
  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
      <input
        id="firstName"
        name="firstName"
        type="text"
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        value={formik.values.firstName}
      />
      <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
      <input
        id="lastName"
        name="lastName"
        type="text"
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        value={formik.values.lastName}
      />
      <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
      <input
        id="email"
        name="email"
        type="email"
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        value={formik.values.email}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onSubmit` event receives a callback function, it can be a normal function or async function:

```
...
onSubmit: async (values) => {
  // await something here...
},
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your "await" inside onSubmit function, and then call the api using axios after "await" keyword.

EXAMPLE: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-wescoff-uh2e3b

CODE:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Field, Form } from "formik";
import axios from "axios";

const Example = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        password: ""
      }}
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
        const user = await axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/login", {
          email: values.email,
          password: values.password
        });
        alert(JSON.stringify(user, null, 2));
      }}
    >
      {({ isSubmitting }) => (
        <Form>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <Field name="firstName" placeholder="Eve" />

          <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <Field name="lastName" placeholder="Holt" />

          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <Field name="email" placeholder="eve.holt@reqres.in" type="email" />

          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <Field name="password" placeholder="cityslicka" type="password" />

          <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```